# Как получить результат выборки без сортировки по первичному ключу? MYSQL

Tags: php, sphinx, mysql

Есть список id который возвращает поисковый движок, эти id потом суются в IN() и достаются из базы, но не в том порядке в котором они были в IN а в порядке возрастания первичного ключа. 
Можно ли сделать выборку так, чтобы результат возвращался в том порядке в котором был задан в IN()?
Хотелось бы решить задачу использую только SQL, т.е. вариант сортировки результатов по релевантности после запрос используя php кажется кривоватым.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MySQL: сортировка выборки в порядке, заданном в операторе IN](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562351/mysql-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-in)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Если у кого-то будет подобный вопрос, оставлю тут пример решения: 
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `id` 
IN ( 5, 1, 4, 2 ) 
ORDER BY FIELD( id, 5, 1, 4, 2 )