# MySQL: сортировка выборки в порядке, заданном в операторе IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выбрать строки с помощью оператора `IN` именно в том порядке, в котором они переданы? Т.е. `SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id IN (2, 3, 1)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `FIELD()`, передав ей точно такую же последовательность, которую вы задаете в `IN`. Функция будет возвращать индекс значения в последовательности и по нему можно отсортировать выборку конструкцией `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT
  id, name
FROM
  users
WHERE
  id IN (2, 3, 1)
ORDER BY
  FIELD(id, 2, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, по шагам, как это будет работать в SQL Server.

Comment: @ВладимирСмирнов К сожалению, FIELD не является стандартной функцией и будет работать только в MySQL и СУБД где она реализована. Боюсь для MS SQL придется подбирать альтернативное решение.

Comment: Да, работает, спасибо! Надо запомнить.