# Как отсортировать mysql таким образом

Tags: mysql, sql, order

Есть данные в базе:

```
id, title
1 - заголовок
2 - заголовок 2
3 - заголовок 3
```

Как отсортировать таким образом, чтобы получить:

```
2 - заголовок 2
1 - заголовок 
3 - заголовок 3
```

К сожалению, `ASC` и `DESC` в данном случаи не подходят.
Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Опишите принцип желаемой сортировки

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MySQL: сортировка выборки в порядке, заданном в операторе IN](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562351/mysql-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-in)

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете отдельный столбец в котором указываете индексы для нужного порядка сортировки. Сортируете, при выводе, по нему.

```
id, title, sortOrder
1, заголовок, 2
2, заголовок 2, 1
3, заголовок 3, 3
```

Запрос:

```
select * from table order by sortOrder
```

Comment: В результате в выдачу выведется ненужный столбец.

Comment: @Denis ну не будем настолько сомневаться в топикстартере, заменить звездочку каждый сможет, как ему надо ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
select id, title
from table
order by case title when "Заголовок 2" then 1
                    when "Заголовок" then 2
                    else 3 end
```

В результате сначала пойдут первыми строки с "Заголовком 2", потом строки с "Заголовком", потом с оставшимся "Заголовком 3".

[Пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/101f96/1/0).

Comment: +1. Абсурдно, но верно )