# Запрет сортировки при выборке where in

Tags: mysql

Делаю выборку к примеру

```
select ... where id IN(11,4,25,1,8)
```

а база сортирует строки (1,4,8,11,25).

Как заставить ее выдавать строки в порядке как в IN ?

Comment: @Visman Предлагаю тот дубль что вы нашли, так же закрыть как дубль со ссылкой на тот, что нашел я. В нем ответ более качественный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562351/mysql-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-in

Comment: @Mike, свой голос я отозвал, но повторно пока не дает голосовать.