# Как при использовании whereIn (Laravel) отключить сортировку?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

перейду пожалуй сразу к делу.

У меня есть запрос

```
$sql = 'select t.* from animes__statuses t where not exists (select 1 from animes__statuses t2 where t2.anime_id = t.anime_id and t2.created_at > t.created_at) AND status_id IN ('.implode(',',$SETTINGS['arStatuses']).') ORDER BY created_at DESC;';
        $animes_statuses = \DB::select($sql);
        $animeIds = array_column($animes_statuses, 'anime_id');

        return isset($SETTINGS['iLimit'])
            ? $query->whereIn('animes.id', $animeIds)->limit($SETTINGS['iLimit'])->get()
            : $query->whereIn('animes.id', $animeIds)->get();
```

В переменной **$animeIds** у меня массив вида **[31,2,27,11,9,24]**

Проблема в **whereIn()** эта функция игнорирует последовательность из **$animeIds** и приводит результат от меньшего в большему что мне не нужно.
Подскажите как исправить запрос чтобы последовательность которая была в **$animeIds** сохранилась.

Comment: Посмотрите тут - [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562351/mysql-сортировка-выборки-в-порядке-заданном-в-операторе-in)

Comment: @Knyaz71 спасибо вам за наводку, всё получилось.